# Android get out of doInBackgroundThread without leaving the activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, background

this all started because I wanted to display a toast message in a background thread. (Toast messages crash the app when trying to load them without telling them to load on UI thread) Now I realize I want to display a toast message AND close the background thread, this is a kind of error handling and letting the user know of the error.

The desired condition in the background thread takes the user to a new activity and finishes the current one. That works.

Now I noticed that I don't know of another way to end the backgroundthread and show the toast message on the same activity?

How do I end the background thread from doInBackground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the cancel() method for your task.  Then when it's cancelled rather than running the onPostExecute() it will call onCancelled().  Put your Toast message in there.

Comment: Thank you, the cancel method closes the dialog box, I can't get onCancelled() to ever execute though!

Comment: In the activity that calls my background thread I have a _initTask.cancel(true) that stops the background thread if the activity stops.  Then in my doInBackground() method I check for this.isCancelled() before attempting a return.  When the doInBackground() detects an isCancelled() it automatically executes the onCancelled() method instead of the onPostExecuteMethod().

Answer (score 0):

RD If I may suggest a rather twisted method of handling errors in a background thread. Consider wrapping the calls in the background thread in a try catch and return a stateful object. So if you want the background thread to return a string, create a BoolString class.

```
//a utility class to signal success or failure, return an error message, and return a useful String value
//see Try Out in C#
public final class BoolString {
 public final boolean success;
 public final String err;
 public final String value;

 public BoolString(boolean success, String err, String value){
     this.success= success;
     this.err= err;
     this.value= value;
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
public BoolString tryEncrypt(String inString, String password) {
    try {
        String value= encrypt(inString, password);
        return new BoolString(true,"",value);
    }
    catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
        return new BoolString(false,e.getMessage(),"");
    }
}

    protected void onPostExecute(BoolString result){          
        progress.dismiss();
        if (result.success){
                result.value;
        }
        else {
              result.err;
        }
    }
```